# How to programmatically distinguish between a TeX and a LaTeX file

Tags: python, latex, tex

I have a big collection of `.tex` files (TeX/LaTeX), and I'm writing a Python script that analyzes these files. I wish only to analyze LaTeX files, thus I want to remove all pure TeX files.

I have thought about making sure `\begin{document}` is contained in every file, but this rejects quite a big amount of my files, since several files are only chapters in a book, long lists, or sections in a dissertation that does not have the `\begin{document}` command.

Does anybody have an idea, how to filter all the pure TeX files away from my collection?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you give a use case where the distinction matters given that you have no idea how to process the files anyway (e.g. they could just be LaTeX fragments containing chapters, or even only collections of options)?

Comment: How about using `\begin{document}` to find the main LaTeX files, and then searching for `\input` and `\include` within those files to find files containing LaTeX fragments. Any file without `\begin{document}` that is not included in a known LaTeX file is then most likely a plain TeX file.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier: I'm trying to determine the most frequently used LaTeX typographical constructs, for a school project.

Comment: @G.Poore: That might be an idea, except if people \include or \input TeX files? Does anybody even do that?

Comment: @G.Poore: Btw, I cannot be sure that I have the files that are tried included. The files are gathered with a crawler, and are all stored in the same directory, so the folder structure/file namings are not the same as original.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's unlikely to be a completely foolproof way of doing this, given that you want to be sensitive to files which can be input with `\input` or `\include`.  Given a particular file, though, you can probably classify it with considerable confidence by spotting the first of the following which you find.

1. TeX files usually *end* with `\bye`, and that's typically not defined in a LaTeX file.
2. The macro `\begin` is unlikely to be defined in a ‘normal’ TeX file (though `\end` is defined in the `plain` format).

That's probably about the best you can do, though it would surely be enough for the sort of statistical analysis you appear to be doing.

There's nothing to stop someone writing a TeX file from defining `\begin` to mean something, nor someone writing a LaTeX file to define `\bye` to mean something.  The problem, from your point of view, is that there aren't *any* TeX constructs that are truly forbidden in a LaTeX file (and vice versa), even though things like `\halign` would be rare in LaTeX.  Indeed, since LaTeX is ‘just’ a TeX format, there isn't any *fundamental* difference between the two, at all.

Just to drive the latter point home, there's such a thing as [ConTeXt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ConTeXt), which is a TeX format which isn't `plain`, but which isn't LaTeX either.  It's rather rare, though.

Answer (score -3):

Yeah sure, add all you file names to array, do this by listing the directory.

```
    x = os.listdir("path")
```

This will add the directory contents to the variable x.
Then loop through it:

```
    PureTex = []
    for Char in x:
        if Char.endswith('.tex'):
            PureTex.append(Char)
        else:
            pass
```

Now the PureTex array will contain the pure files.

Comment: His problem is that in typical convention *both TeX and LaTeX files end with `.tex`*.